# How to log a CGVector?

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

Hopefully the title is self-explanatory. I am sure this is an easy answer but I am a bit of a noob when it comes to Objective-C. I am looking to NSLog a CGVector because I want to see if the velocity of a sprite is increasing as it should. Thanks in advance!

Comment: other approach,  NSLog(@"dx: %f, dy: %f", yourVector.dx, yourVector.dy);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGVector(vec));`